# Создание бургера

Tags: javascript, html, css

Проблема состоит в том что вручную active добавляется и код работает, а js прописываю и никакой реакции и ошибку не могу найти

```js
let burger = document.querySelector(".dribble__burger");
burger.addEventListener(`click`, function() {
  burger.classList.toggle(`active`);
})
```

```css
.dribble__burger {
  position: relative;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.dribble__burger span {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #9e9ea7;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}

.dribble__burger span:nth-last-of-type(2) {
  top: calc(50% - 5px);
}

.dribble__burger span:nth-last-of-type(3) {
  top: calc(50% + 5px);
}

@media(max-width:915px) {
  .drible__ul {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
    flex-direction: column;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    background-color: green;
  }
  .dribble__burger.active span:first-of-type{
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .dribble__burger.active span:nth-of-type(2) {
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(45deg);
  }
  .dribble__burger.active span:nth-of-type(3) {
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="dribble__burger">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

В данный момент ваш пример работает, но есть проблема

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возможно в этом проблема, тогда стоит убрать `.dribble__burger span` свойство `left: 50%;` до `0`.

Второй момент: думаю вы помните что крести появляется только при `@media(max-width:915px)`

Третий момент: поменяйте на кавычки одинарные тут `'click'` и тут `'active'`

Comment: спасибо за ответ, все способы попробовал, но увы пока что ничего не изменилось

Comment: В примере работает, или что-то по другому должно быть?

Comment: да, у меня странно выходит, в примере действительно работает, а в VS и на странице не совсем...

Comment: Посмотрите через инструменты разработчика что у вас происходит, или дополните пример

Comment: загрузил проэкт https://jsfiddle.net/QMadHatterQ/1znL8omq/, здесь тоже все работает.

Comment: @ВадимВадимыч нашли проблему? может весь код поместить сюда `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {....});`

Comment: еще не нашел, попробую отдельно открыть документы css,html. Я просто начал делать многостраничник, и возможно в общий стилях, есть что-то, что мешает работе, потому что гите и здесь, код работает как должен. Поэтому как все попробую, отпишусь.

Comment: проблема заключалась, в месте подключения js файла, я его обычно подключаю в самом начале, но после того как перенес в конец всех тегов, проблема разрешилась) но все равно спасибо большое за уделенное время)